# How did Chandrakanta reach the cave visible from Tej Singh's garden prison?

Tags: chandrakanta

After Chandrakanta and Chapla escaped Chunargadh prison, they reached a *Tilism* house. Inside it, a stone egret swallowed Chandrakanta and somehow she reached the cave where Virendra Singh saw her for the first time after her kidnap (but, he couldn't free her).

To understand the map, first, let's see how Chapla reached there:

- She backed away when stone egret started to move.
- In a room, she found a well. When she dropped fire to light it up, she found a stone man sitting and reading book.
- In the next room, she found a stone man sleeping and reading a book on a high bed. The stairs to bed couldn't let her climb.
- In the next room, she found a trap door on the floor. She beat the auto shut mechanism by holding the door with rope and climbed down. But, she got locked in by another door.
- She exited in a garden. In this garden, she found a throne on which there was a stone. This stone had text saying whoever would break the *Tilism* would get enormous wealth and would be able to free prisoners.
- From here, she swam down the river stream to get out of walls and followed that stream and then reached the waterfall source. Next, she was able to climb to Chandrakanta which are unnecessary details.

We later learn that swimming down the river stream was necessary part of reaching that cave. But, before that, one need to reach the garden with thorne. Virendra Singh reached that garden by another underground way which started in the room in which stone man was sleeping. Previously, when he blew out the stone egret, there was an underground way leading to the well in which a stone man was sitting.

So, after getting swallowed by stone egret, Chandrakanta could get to the well only. How did she reach the garden with throne from there?

Comment: Are you referring to the book or the campy 1990s TV show?

Comment: @Valorum Both should be same. But, I am referring books.

Comment: Did this incident happen in both the book and the TV show?

Comment: @Valorum Yeah. This is core to the story. But, book has more details as always.